# GeoExt: Using children node not expanded problem in check function

Tags: geoext, ext-js, heron-mapping-client

I'm using children in a Geoext tree definition.

If the node is expanded the function to see if children is checked or not (see the code) works, however when the node is not expanded it seems that the children are not defined.

Any suggestions as to why this is occurring?

```
    var childrenTotal = 0, childrenChecked = 0;
    var self = this;
    this.cascade(function (child) {
        // Don't check ourselves nor any other directory nodes that are not cascaders
        if (child == self || (child.hasChildNodes() && !child.attributes.xtype == 'hr_cascader')) {
            return;
        }

        childrenTotal++;
        if (child.ui.isChecked()) {
            childrenChecked++;
        }
    }, null, null);
```

Comment: It seems that if the tree is not expanded child are not defined...

Comment: probably the problem is due to the option preloadChildren:true https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282582-How-to-refresh-the-tree-panel-view-in-ExtJs3.4

Comment: Anyone have ideas??